# Redmine - how to run as fastcgi with nginx?

Tags: nginx, ruby, ruby-on-rails, redmine, fastcgi

I have installed redmine on one of my Ubuntu 14.04 servers. 
So far works perfectly, postgre-db created and filled, and it runs with

```
ruby script/rails server webrick -e production -b 10.0.0.20
```

Now I want to run it behing nginx.
The first tutorial I found was with phusionpassenger, but phusionpassenger doesn't work with the version of ruby shipped by ubuntu. 
I tried puma, and that works. However, I don't want to reverse-proxy. 
I want to run redmine as fastcgi application.

So I tried trunning it with dispatch.fcgi

```
export RAILS_ENV="production"
export RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=""
export RAILS_ROOT="/usr/share/redmine/"
export SOCKET_FILE="/var/run/redmine-application.sock"
export PID_FILE="/var/run/redmine-application.pid"
export DEAMON_USER="postgres"
export SOCKET_USER="www-data"


exec /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -P $PID_FILE -s $SOCKET_FILE -U $SOCKET_USER -u $DEAMON_USER -- $RAILS_ROOT/public/dispatch.fcgi
```

At first, I got

> You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your development environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log at config/environments/development.rb

until I discovered that I need to run it from working-directory `/usr/share/redmine`

However, there's no fcgi-service running after spawn. 
I get no error message either.

I tried starting redmine cgi manually (as root):

```
cd /usr/share/redmine/
/usr/share/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi
```

However, I don't get where I can set the socket file or TCP-port... 
Where can I configure that ?

I tried

```
/usr/share/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi -socket "/var/run/redmine.sock"
```

and

```
/usr/share/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi -socket="/var/run/redmine.sock"
```

as well as specifiying socket in the env-variables, but it does not seem to have any effect.

How can I spawn redmine as ruby fastcgi-process with tcp-port/unix-socket ?